# Estimation of stochastic parameters in bivariate Poisson model

Tags: estimation, poisson-distribution, bivariate

I need to estimate parameters in bivariate Poisson model. Formulas for parameters:
$\lambda_1= exp (\alpha_i-\beta_i+\delta)$

$\lambda_2= exp (\alpha_j-\beta_j)$

where delta is some constant, alpha and beta are autoregressive processes with not necessarily gaussian noise:

$\alpha_{i,t}= \mu_{\alpha}+\phi_i\alpha_{i-1,t}+\epsilon_{\alpha}$

$\beta_{i,t}= \mu_{\beta}+\phi_i\beta_{i-1,t}+\epsilon_{\beta}$

I have around 400 pairs of data points $(X_1,Y_1),...,(X_{400},Y_{400})$. I am struggling with estimation of the parameters. Any ideas how to proceed or papers regarding above will be much appreciated. Thank you.